# Bash for loop on directories

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop, directory

I have a bash script that I'd like to run a program in one directory, using a file from another directory as input

There are several input files, located in several different directories, each of which is used as input for one iteration of the program

The files are one filetype (.foo) of several in each of these directories

My code is

```
cd /path/to/data/
for D in *; do
    # command 1
    if [ -d "$D" ]
    then
        cd /path/to/data
        # command 2
        for i in *.foo
        do
            # command 3
        done
    fi
done
```

When I run the script, the output is as follows

```
# command 1 output
# command 2 output
# command 3 output
# command 2 output
# command 2 output
# command 2 output
# command 2 output
# command 2 output
.
.
.
```

So the script does what I expect it to do exactly once, and then seems to not iterate over the final for loop after that

Why is this?

Comment: You changed directory and changed it not back? Your code is unclear because you used twice `cd /path/to/data/`.

Comment: Generally, try to avoid using `cd` in a script, you can tie yourself in knots.  It is easier to construct and use full path names wherever possible.  For example:  `for i in /path/to/data/*.foo`.

Comment: What do those commands do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo error after "then"... 
It makes more sense to be:

```
then
  cd /path/to/data/$D
  # command 2
```

But as advised by cdarke, it is good to avoid to use cd in your script.
You can have the same result like this:

```
for D in /path/to/data; do
    # command 1
    if [ -d "$D" ]
    then
        # command 2
        for i in /path/to/data/$D/*.foo
        do
            # command 3
        done
    fi
done
```

Or you could even use find and avoid the if parts (less code makes faster your script):

```
for D in $(find /path/to/data -maxdepth 1 -type d)
# -type d in find get's only directories
# -maxdepth 1 means current dir. If you remove maxdepth option all subdirs will be found. 
# OR you can increase -maxdepth value to control how deep you want to search inside sub directories.
```